# docker-compose volumes: ./var:/var error?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
    mysql56:
        image: mysql:5.6
        container_name: mysql56
        volumes:
            # - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./var:/var
        ports:
            - 3307:3306
            - 33060:33060
        environment:
            TZ: Asia/Shanghai
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root@123'
        networks:
            - shanhy-ci
networks:
    shanhy-ci:
        driver: bridge
```

run:

```
docker-compose up
```

It outputs error:

```
Creating mysql56 ... error
...
merged/var/lib: file exists\\\"\"": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

But if I modify `docker-compose.yml`：

```
volumes:
    - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    # - ./var:/var
```

So he can work normally, I don't know why,

Why does `docker` have`/var/lib/mysql`, but does not have `/var`?

`image: mysql:5.6` : https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/4ee6cf34697d33b2f71144ef55f96867b71220d5/5.6/Dockerfile

Comment: There’s a lot of stuff in `/var` beyond just the MySQL data, and I won’t be surprised if bind-mounting an empty host directory over it causes problems.

Comment: Doesn't he sync the docker files over? 
But synchronize the files of the host to docker?

Comment: The bind mount hides everything in the container on that path, and replaces it with the host content.  There’s not a “sync” or “merge” operation.